# HTML/CSS scrollable <div></div> shows the bottom of element when loaded instead of top

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have div that is vertically scroll able. The problem is when the div loads it displays the bottom of the div instead of the top. Can't make it display the top. Any suggestions?

Javascript code to activate it when clicked:

```
 var pbody = document.getElementById("pbody");
 pbody.style.display = "block";
```

HTML:

```
<div id="pbody">
         text stuff
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
#pbody {
    display: none;
    position: relative;
    width: 800px;
    height: 2000px;
    background-color: black;
    border-radius: 100px;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 200;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Happen to have a link to an example? It's always difficult to diagnose these types of things without seeing them.

Comment: no, basically i would have to port the whole website to one of those test website links.

Comment: Sounds weird to me. Usually that should not happen. I assume that the problem is related to something else in your code.

Comment: Your code supplied does not have the problem you describe. Here is a fiddle showing it working fine: http://jsfiddle.net/TruQG/. If you cannot recreate the problem in an example, or supply code to recreate the problem, then we cannot help you.

Comment: I'm assuming javascript adds the display of block on a click event? If so, this is kind of a "popup" div. In that case you should position it absolutely, add a `top` of 10px and add a `left` of like 32%.